# Modifying NMEA of Adafruit GPS

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit, gps

I use a Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout - 66 channel w/10 Hz updates to collect data on animal movement.

I have two questions regarding the produced NMEA:
- there are some information about PGACK, PMTK that are produced in the code that I don't need. Do you know a way of not including it?
- I'd like to add some information in the NMEA line, but when I do it, it creates a space between the NMEA and the new information that do not allow me to process it correctly then in Excel or R. This is the information I've added:

```
fichier.print(buffer);
fichier.print(",");
fichier.print(GPS.hour, DEC);
fichier.print(':');
fichier.print(GPS.minute, DEC);
fichier.print(':');
fichier.print(GPS.seconds, DEC);
fichier.print(",");
fichier.print(GPS.day, DEC); fichier.print('/');
fichier.print(GPS.month, DEC); fichier.print("/20");
fichier.print(GPS.year, DEC);
fichier.print(",");
fichier.println(j);
fichier.close();
acquisition = true;
```

Comment: show us the output now and how it should be, not sure what "produced NMEA" means

Comment: please explain what this means ... `do not allow me to process it correctly`